# How can I read also the temperature with this GSR sensor?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, temperature-sensor

Considering the GSR is the inverse of the Resistance, if I know the resistance and how much it increases for every celsius degree, the game would be done.
Here's how my code looks like at the moment:

```
const int GSR=A0;
int threshold=0;
int sensorValue;
const long interval = 1000; 
unsigned long T = millis();


void setup(){
  long sum=0;
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);

  for(int i=0;i<500;i++)
  {
  sensorValue=analogRead(GSR);
  sum += sensorValue;
  delay(5);
  }
  threshold = sum/500;
   Serial.print("threshold =");
   Serial.println(threshold);
  }

void loop(){


  if( millis() - T >= 250)  {
   int temp;
  sensorValue=analogRead(GSR);
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  temp = threshold - sensorValue;
  T = millis();

  }
  }
```

The page of the sensor:
http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_-_GSR_Sensor

Comment: The GSR measures resistance. You have temperature. -> What is the formula to transform temp to res in your case? Why don't U use a simple lm35, pt100 or do it digitally with ds18b20? A matter of minutes.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/c/8/e/c8e9a28af18315880dd5090267057812.png

Here's the equation to do it
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance